# plotAreaWasSelected is not called when running app on the device

Tags: ios, core-plot

I am using core-plot to draw a simple scatter plot, and I want to do something when the plot area delegate "plotAreaWasSelected" was called. 
It all works well when I use the iOS simulator to test the app, but when I change to a real iOS device, the delegate method is never called. And I found the core-plot demo example has the same problem.
Does anyone have the same  problem? I am confused about this and hope someone can help.

I am using Xcode 6.0.1 and my device is iOS7.1, and the simulator is iOS8.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself.
In the core-plot source code, I saw this:

```
CGPoint lastPoint = self.touchedPoint;

// omit some codes......

// !!!!! the second condition of the if sentence cause my problem !!!!!
if ( CGRectContainsPoint(self.bounds, plotAreaPoint) && CGPointEqualToPoint(plotAreaPoint, lastPoint) ) {
        if ( [theDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(plotAreaTouchUp:)] ) {
            [theDelegate plotAreaTouchUp:self];
        }

        if ( [theDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(plotAreaTouchUp:withEvent:)] ) {
            [theDelegate plotAreaTouchUp:self withEvent:event];
        }

        if ( [theDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(plotAreaWasSelected:)] ) {
            [theDelegate plotAreaWasSelected:self];
        }

        if ( [theDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(plotAreaWasSelected:withEvent:)] ) {
            [theDelegate plotAreaWasSelected:self withEvent:event];
        }

        return NO; // don't block other events in the responder chain
    }
```

In real device environment, the touch begin point and the touch end point are usually different from each other, they are always not the same.
So the condition `CGPointEqualToPoint(plotAreaPoint, lastPoint)` is always false and codes inside the if sentence never be executed.
To fit this I deleted the second condition in if:

```
if ( CGRectContainsPoint(self.bounds, plotAreaPoint)) { ... }
```

And it was solved.

Comment: I just fixed this in [Core Plot](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot). I changed the check you removed so that it allows the ending point to be up to five points away from the starting point and still fire the selection methods on the delegate.